# ¿Porque no pasan todas las variables por metodo GET en C#?

Tags: c#, mvc, razor, controller

Tengo el siguiente controlador para recibir parametros por get

Yo envio mi url asi http://localhost:63424/Sales/UsarCode/?rmail=miemail@domain.com&rcompany=restorevitalite&raddress=rfm%20xs%20xs&rpais=59&rtel=56581111&rhash=fsdff&ridpalpay=123&rpriority=2&rtel=6

```
public ActionResult UsarCode(string rmail, string rcompany, string raddress, string rpais, string rtel, string rhash, string ridpalpay, string rpriority, string idproduct)
        {
            using (ArcsaEntities ctx = new ArcsaEntities())
            {
                var pack = ctx.SalesArcsaReportsPakages.Where(p => p.hass == rhash).FirstOrDefault();
                if (pack.hass == rhash && pack.status == true)
                {
                    SalesARCSASearchFront searchFront = new SalesARCSASearchFront();

                    searchFront.fkSalesPayPal = Convert.ToInt32(ridpalpay);
                    searchFront.CorreoElectronico = rmail;
                    searchFront.Query = rcompany;
                    searchFront.Telefono = rtel;
                    searchFront.Direccion = raddress;
                    searchFront.fkProductARCSA = 2;
                    searchFront.fkCountry = Convert.ToInt32(rpais);
                    searchFront.CreatAt = DateTime.Now;
                    searchFront.UpdateAt = DateTime.Now;
                    ctx.SalesARCSASearchFront.Add(searchFront);
                    ctx.SaveChanges();

                    string uri = "http://189.240.112.242/arcsaws/arcsausa.asmx/OrderOfflineARCSAusa?key=S232Q334K320U314Q302L328S200X214O198O196I198B196P170&TypeOfReport=2&idSearchFrontARCSA=" + searchFront.Id;
                    var request = WebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;
                    var response = request.GetResponse();

                    Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                    StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);

                    var resultadoweb = readStream.ReadToEnd();
                    //Create the XmlDocument.
                    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                    xmlDoc.LoadXml(resultadoweb);
                    XmlNodeList elemlist = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Result");
                    XmlNodeList elemlist2 = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("IdReport");
                    string suc = elemlist[0].InnerXml;
                    string reporte = elemlist2[0].InnerXml;
                    var insertfkreport = ctx.SalesARCSASearchFront.Where(i => i.Id == searchFront.Id).FirstOrDefault();
                    insertfkreport.fkReport = Convert.ToInt32(reporte);
                    ctx.SaveChanges();

                    RequestedReportsARCSA requesteReport = new RequestedReportsARCSA();
                    requesteReport.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
                    requesteReport.fkSalesArcsaReportsPakage = pack.id;
                    requesteReport.Telefono = rtel;
                    requesteReport.Direccion = raddress;
                    requesteReport.Company = rcompany;
                    requesteReport.fkCountry = Convert.ToInt32(rpais);
                    ctx.RequestedReportsARCSA.Add(requesteReport);
                    ctx.SaveChanges();

                    var Conteo = ctx.RequestedReportsARCSA.Where(c => c.fkSalesArcsaReportsPakage == pack.id).Count();
                    if (Conteo == pack.Quantity)
                    {
                        pack.status = false;
                        ctx.SaveChanges();
                    }
                    ViewBag.Reporte = reporte;
                    ViewBag.Email = rmail;

                    return View("~/Views/Sales/Congratulations_2.cshtml");
                }
                return Content("Error de procesamiento 701");
            }
        }
```

Puse un punto de interrupción pero solo llegan ciertas variables como email rhash pero las demás no las toma alguien me podría explicar porque, Gracias

Comment: No sé si es el problema pero ya te diste cuenta que "rtel" lo duplicas y no incluyes "idproduct"

Comment: gracias a pesar de la corrección sigue sin tomar todas las variables

Comment: Intenta no escribir en rmail algun textco sin arroba ni punto

Comment: ya lo intente y no funciona solo recibe rmail y rhash, los demás vienen vacíos

Comment: Acabo de hacer una prueba, y sí funcionan todos los parametros. En dónde tienes el punto de interrupción? como sabes que no tienen valor los parámetros?

Comment: lo pongo exactamente despues del public exactamente en la llave de apertura {, al poner el mouse sobre cada item por ejemplo rmail me sale un tooltip emergente con el mail pero en los demas vacio menos rhash y si voy dando f10 noto que al llamar las demas variables viene null

Comment: Exactamente eso es lo que hago y sí llegan los valores. Si pudieras subirlo a algún repositorio con mucho gusto puedo ayudarte a ver si es algo más.